# KendoUI and Angular2 autocomplete: restrict values

Tags: angular, autocomplete, kendo-ui-angular2

I have implemented the KendoUI Autocomplete with a live search when typing. This works quite fine and as expected.

However, I would like it to be restricted to the values in the list only. So basically, if I type "London" and it suggests "London, UK" and "London, Canada" I should be forced to use one of those and not be able to leave "London" or even type "London, My own Kingdom".

Is there any way to restrict the value? I haven't found any option in the API unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kendo AutoComplete is designed to allow custom values and to behave more like a Google search input.

If you would like to control the input value, then it will be better to use the ComboBox component and just hide the `toggle` button:

```
styles: [`
.k-combobox .k-select {
  display: none
}

.k-combobox .k-input {
  padding-right: 0;
}

.k-combobox .k-dropdown-wrap .k-i-close {
  right: 4px;
}
`],
```

Here is a runnable plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/iJlwcPFj8Oj5AVyF2RbX?p=preview

The other benefit is that the list will maintain the selected item unlike the autocomplete.

Comment: thanks, that works like a charm! However, now I'm facing another issue: I don't want to hide the entire k-select, since the loader is displayed in there too. I tried to add a custom class to k-combobox in order to be able to hide it and show when the .loading property is true:

<kendo-combobox [ngClass]="{loading: myCombobox.loading}

however, I get ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError when executing. Any idea?

Comment: I suppose that it will be better to raise `loading` flag separately once the data is received and to not depend on the combobox.loading flag. Anyways, the solutions is always to put the change in a tick (either setTimeout, Promise or requestAnimationFrame). If you can post a plunkr, I will try to find a solution for you.

Comment: Actually, I just managed to do it. I'm adding a class "loading" to the combobox depending on whether its loading flag is set to true or not. And with css I then show the loader or hide the toggle button. Works perfectly. Thanks anyway :)